# setText crashes my app - inStream.read

Tags: android, crash, stream, textview, settext

I have a problem with setText( TextView ).

```
view        = EgridView.getChildAt( iterator );
parameter   = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.gridItemParameter );


if( modbus.readAvailable() > 0 ){
    if( !((data = modbus.readData()).equals("")) ){





Log.i("-------------TEST-----------", data); // <-------- wrok
//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), data , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); <----- work
// parameter.setText( "test" ); <----------- work
parameter.setText( data ); // <--------- crash





    }
}
```

**Why **parameter.setText( data ); **crashes my app?**

---

More code:

```
public int readAvailable(){
    try{
        return inStream.available();
    }  catch( Exception e ){
        return 0;
    }
}

public String readData(){
    try{
        if( isConnected == true && socket.isConnected() && inStream != null ){
            int     i;
            int     oneByte;

            byte    byteArray[] = new byte[ 100 ];

            int     available   = inStream.available();
            String  data        = "";                                               

            if( available > 0 ){
                inStream.read( byteArray );

                for( i = 0; i < available; i++ ){
                    oneByte  = byteArray[ i ] & 0xff;
                    data = data.concat( Integer.toString( oneByte ) + " " );
                }                                                                               

                return data; // <-----
            } else {
                    return "";
            }
        } else {
            errorText = "no communication";
            return "";
        }

    } catch( Exception e ){
        errorText = e.getMessage();

        return "";
    }
}
```

If in readData() I write **return "test";** then work

If in readData() I write **return  byteArray.toString();** then work

If in readData() I write **for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){** then work

If in readData() I write **for( i = 0; i < 11; i++ ){** then **crashes**

int available = 13 in this situation.

My problem is illogical for me. Please advice.

Thanks for all answers

Comment: I believe it's a typo, but `arameter    = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.gridItemParameter );` name is missing p as in `parameter`

Comment: Can you try parameter.setText(String.valueOf(data)); I am not sure but may work. And I assume the "paramater" object is not null.

Comment: And can you paste the error you are getting?

Comment: http://paste2.org/vJ5fOPvO - error.But it is not null - Toast.makeText work good.

Of course it is parameter not arameter  - sorry.
String.valueOf(data) - don't work

Answer (score 0):

You can only modify UI elements, such as the TextView, on the UI Thread.

Check this link out from the android documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 0):

i guess your FINAL STRING Data

make the data cannot be filled

so your variable Data is still null

and you try to setText (null) , that's why..

try to change Final String Data to String Data = ""

or

if there is a problem with your readData function

try this solution

```
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append((line + "\n"));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close(); 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(con, "Return Nya = " +sb.toString(), 0).show();
            Log.v("TEST" , "Return Nya = " + sb.toString());

            is.close();
```

Comment: I had >String Data = "";<, but I use runOnUiThread, so I have to write final String .